# vlc installed but not opening when clicked in ubuntu 1404

Tags: 14.04, startup, vlc

When I use vlc command in terminal

```
$ vlc
vlc: error while loading shared libraries: libvlc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

this error can happen when a you compile a library and do the install yet the freshly installed library is not yet registered to the system ... if that is the case just issue this

```
sudo ldconfig
```

then vlc will find the library and launch OK

when compiling c++ projects from source, like vlc, this is necessary to register the dynamic libraries ... after the `sudo make install`

I am on ubuntu 18.04 installing vlc 4.0 from source

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
sudo apt-get install libvlc5
```

If it's already installed, you may also need to link your local libraries to the system libraries :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libvlc* /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libx264.a /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/vlc /usr/lib/vlc
```

Comment: nothing has changed

Comment: How did you installed Vlc?

Comment: software center

Comment: its  not working

Comment: vlc: error while loading shared libraries: libvlc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory